# How can I read the special XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have one special XML file , the contenct of the XML file is as follows :

```
<b title="FunctionalCI">ApplicationSolution</b>::42<br/>
<ul class="treeview">
<li>Name = Sep11</li>
<li>Description = <div ></div></li>
<li>Organization = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=Organization&id=4&" title="Organization::4">test</a></li>
<li>Organization name = test</li>
<li>Business criticity = <span title="high">high</span></li>
<li>Move to production date = 2014-12-31</li>
<li>Contacts = </li>
<li>Documents = </li>
<li>Application solutions = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=ApplicationSolution&id=53&" title="Application Solution::53">Sep Engine CO04</a>, 53 42, Sep Engine CO04, Sep11</li>
<li>Provider contracts = </li>
<li>Services = </li>
<li>Softwares = </li>
<li>Tickets = </li>`
<li>CIs = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=50&" title="Functional CI::50">Sep Console05</a>, 42 50, Sep11, Sep Console05<br/><a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=53&" title="Functional CI::53">Sep Engine CO04</a>, 42 53, Sep11, Sep Engine CO04</li>
<li>Business processes = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=BusinessProcess&id=44&" title="Business Process::44">Business Process</a>, 44 42, Business Process, Sep11</li>
<li>Status = <span title="active">active</span></li>
<li>map level = 2</li>
<li>CI Type = Application Solution</li>
<li>Friendly name = Sep11</li>
<li>Organization = test</li>
</ul>
<b title="FunctionalCI">WebApplication</b>::50<br/>
<ul class="treeview">
<li>Name = Sep Console05</li>
<li>Description = <div ></div></li>
<li>Organization = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=Organization&id=4&" title="Organization::4">test</a></li>
<li>Organization name = test</li>
<li>Business criticity = <span title="low">low</span></li>
<li>Move to production date = 2014-12-31</li>
<li>Contacts = </li>
<li>Documents = </li>
<li>Application solutions = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=ApplicationSolution&id=42&" title="Application Solution::42">Sep11</a>, 42 50, Sep11, Sep Console05</li>
<li>Provider contracts = </li>
<li>Services = </li>
<li>Softwares = </li>
<li>Tickets = </li>
<li>Web server = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=WebServer&id=46&" title="Web server::46">Apache http server INFRAVICO05</a></li>
<li>Web server name = Apache http server</li>
<li>URL = <a target="_blank" href=""></a></li>
<li>map level = 3</li>
<li>CI Type = Web Application</li>
<li>Friendly name = Sep Console05</li>
<li>Organization = test</li>
<li>Web server = Apache http server INFRAVICO05</li>
</ul>
```

In this file,as you can see , there are diffirent type of tags like"li,br,ul,a". I want to read the values of each of the tags.
How can I read the values of the tags of the file , please ?

Thanks all of you !

Comment: Well it isn't valid XML because it doesn't have a root element; otherwise it looks more like HTML markup, so why not use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)?

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention it. The above contenct is saved XML format(name of the file is result.xml),but it didn't containt XML header "<?xml version="1.0" ?>" . I try to load the file into php with $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->load('result.xml'); but there is error . Thanks all of you !

Comment: `There is error`.... perhaps telling us __what__ error you get might help

Comment: @MarkBaker ,yes , you are right . the file is simply saved as XML format ,but it doesn't have root element . I tried to read with $doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->load('result.xml'); but, the DOMDocument couldn't load the file. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaker , the error is : "Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Extra content at the end of the document in file:result.xml" . Thanks

Comment: It reports `extra content at the end of the document` **because** the file does not have a root element. You need to fix that, then it will load.

Comment: Or just load it as HTML with `DOMDocument::loadHtmlFile()`. For extracting data, use `DOMXPath::evaluate()`.

Comment: @Arjan I added the lines "<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">" at the begining of the result.xml file ; and the lines "</data>" at the end of the file ; and then I try to read the file with  $doc->load('result.xml');  but, still it could not read the file.Thanks!

Comment: @ThW , first I saved the file as result.html , file content is same as before. and then I try to read the file with " $doc->loadHtmlFile('result.html'); " ,but it didn't work. Thanks !

Comment: The file extension is not relevant. Describe the error you get. Try to debug it (Is the file not found? What's the result of the load method? Save the DOM as XML and output it. ...). Add the PHP source to your question.

Comment: @ThW Ok,I got it. There are two errors.one is " Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in result.html, line: 5" ;the line5 is "<li>Organization = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=Organization&id=4&" title="Organization::4">test</a></li>";another error is " Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in result.html, line: 5"

Comment: @ThW ,the error is said that almost each line there are : "htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' " and "htmlParseEntityRef: no name" .Why theis error occur ? thanks !

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. You haven unescaped (invalid) `&` in the HTML. DOMDocument will fix most of that kind of problems. You can use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` to avoid the output.

Comment: @ThW,yes , you are right ! with "var_dump(libxml_use_internal_errors(true));" , it shows me : " boolean false" .And now it didn't show me the warning .